# Автоответчик в помощнике

Tags: php

Пишу для интернет магазина онлайн помощник. Там обычный коммет чат. Задача сделать автоответчик, если нету никого из менеджеров в сети. Помогите советом. Для начало реализовал базу вопросов с ответами.

```
1) Вопрос 1
   1) Ответ 1
      1) Вариант ответа 1
      2) Вариант ответа 2
       ....

   2) Ответ 2
    ....
2) Вопрос 2
....
```

Это как операторам сотовых компаний звонишь и там прежде чем связать с оператором есть варианты (заготовки) готовых решений (Для чего-то нажмите один. Для того нажмите 2 и т.д.)

Все варианты ответов сопровождаются действиями, например:

```
1) Как добраться до нас
  1) Пешком
  2) На машине
```

Посетитель отправляет в чат 1- ку и получает в ответ два варината, отправляет 2 и сайт редиректиться на страницу со схемами проезда итд.

Встал вопрос как реализовать клиентскую часть. Загружать все вопросы/ответы клиенту и обрабатывать на стороне клиента, или же все запросы обрабатывать на стороне сервера?

Comment: Зависит от размера и логики. Я бы оставил на сервере. Хотя бы на тот случай, если в будущем автоответчику решат добавить ума, и если пошаговая навигация ничего не дала, то прикрутят, например, поиск по тексту вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопросов и ответов не много, можно при открытии чата загрузить их в переменную. Если иначе, то соответственно.

Comment: я думаю их не будет много...100-200 строк в базе всего. для них есть интерфейс в админке...можно добавлять и удалять. я Вот думаю подгружать не сразу, а после когда открывается помощник... сам сайт на аяксе, не перезагружается